# Выравнивание текста внутри Label

Tags: python, tkinter, текст, label

Вечер добрый! Хотел полюбопытствовать, существует ли какой-то способ выравнивания текста внутри текстовой метки? В сети информации не нашел, либо как-то не так ищу. Пример программы ниже. В моем случае нужно выполнить выравнивание по левому краю текстовой метки:
[P.S.: картинки работать не будут]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
 
app = tk.Tk()
app.title('ARSiS assistant')
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'Lightning.png')
app.iconphoto(False, icon)
app.geometry('400x600')
app.resizable(width = False, height = False)
app['background'] = '#B2DFDB'

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------App Interface
#---------------------------------------------------------Logo Section
ttk.Style().configure('TLabel', background = '#B2DFDB')
ARSiS_Logo = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'H:\PYTHON\ARSiS\Materials\ARSiS Logo_m.png')
label = ttk.Label(image = ARSiS_Logo, anchor = "c")
label.place(width = 400, relx =.5, anchor = "n")

#---------------------------------------------------------Patient Section
patientTitle = ttk.Label(text = 'ПАЦИЕНТ:', font = ('Tahoma', 8, 'bold'),
                         foreground = '#2E4D4A', background = '#B2DFDB', padding = 6)
patientTitle.place(y = 128, width = 400)

patientName = tk.StringVar()
patientNameLabel = tk.Label(text = 'ФИО:', font = ('Tahoma', 8),
                            foreground = '#2E4D4A', background = '#B2DFDB')
patientNameLabel.place(x = 6, y = 165, anchor = 'w')
patientName_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = patientName, relief = 'flat')
patientName_entry.place(x = 40, y = 165, relwidth = .87, anchor = 'w')

patientDate = tk.StringVar()
patientDateLabel = tk.Label(text = 'Дата рождения:', font = ('Tahoma', 8),
                            foreground = '#2E4D4A', background = '#B2DFDB')
patientDateLabel.place(x = 6, y = 195, anchor = 'w')
patientDate_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = patientDate, relief = 'flat')
patientDate_entry.place(x = 97, y = 195, relwidth = .25, anchor = 'w')

patientSexLabel = tk.Label(text = "Пол:", font = ('Tahoma', 8),
                           foreground = '#2E4D4A', background = '#B2DFDB')
patientSexLabel.place(x = 206, y = 195, anchor = 'w')
patientSelectSex = ttk.Combobox(app, values = ['мужской',
                                               'женский'])
patientSelectSex.place(x = 235, y = 195, relwidth = .25, anchor = 'w')

def clearPatientValues ():
    patientName_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    patientDate_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    patientSelectSex.set('')

ClearIcon = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'H:\PYTHON\ARSiS\Materials\Clear Icon.png')
ClearIcon = ClearIcon.subsample(42, 42)
clearPatientValues = tk.Button(image = ClearIcon, relief = 'flat',
                               background = '#FFFFFF', command = clearPatientValues)
clearPatientValues.place(x = 367, y = 195, relheight = .035, relwidth = .052, anchor = 'w')

#---------------------------------------------------------Parameters Section
#----------Title
patientTitle = ttk.Label(text = 'АНАМНЕЗ / ДАННЫЕ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ:', font = ('Tahoma', 8, 'bold'),
                         foreground = '#2E4D4A', background = '#B2DFDB', padding = 6)
patientTitle.place(y = 230, width = 400)

#----------Hearth Select
hearthLabel = tk.Label(text = 'Очаг ишемического инсульта в любом из диаметров, \nпо данным КТ или МРТ головного мозга:',
                       font = ('Tahoma', 8), foreground = '#2E4D4A', relief="groove")
hearthLabel.place(x = 8, y = 327, anchor = 'w')

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

параметр anchor задает выравнивание текста на этикетке

```
Label(root, text='text', anchor=tkinter.W)
```

или

```
 Label(root, text='text', justify=tkinter.LEFT)
```

первый дает больше возможностей позиционирования

в обоих случаях можно вместо констант tkinter задавать положение текстом `'w'`

Comment: Попробовал. В первом случае выдает: 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "H:/PYTHON/ARSiS/Native Builds/build_003.py", line 65, in <module>
    anchor = W, relief="groove")
NameError: name 'W' is not defined

А вот второй сработал! Спасибо большое!

Comment: попробовал `tk.Label(root, text='text', anchor=tk.W, bg='yellow', width=50).pack(expand=True)` - прерасно работает

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую еще раз, отпишусь. Пока второй вариант хорошо выручает.